# Blank pages after converting to rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After converting from rails 3.2 to rails 4.1 it renders blank pages on each action. 
Just

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-17 10:50:59 +0300
Processing by SomeController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 303ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

What have I missed in my configs? Route error?

==== **UPDATED** =====

I have a view in app/views/some/index.html.erb
With code like

```
somestring code
<script>
  somejscode
</script>
```

rendered html seems to be empty (except chrome addons js):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"> </pre>
    <script src="//dl.metabar.ru/static/js/ecomerce-context-sovetnik-vks.js" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>
    <iframe src="https://dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/index.html" style="display: none;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

rails s log is:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-17 11:24:02 +0300
Processing by SomeController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 262ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

==== **UPDATED** ====

layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />


    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <%= yield %>


    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

==== **UPDATED** ====

Seems like it renders something similar to `render nothing: true` because it renders `[" "]`.
I've made `egrep -R "render nothing" .` but found nothing helpful. Any suggestions?

```
render body: File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/some/index.html.erb")
```

Is working, but it's not good decision.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you hit that action?

Comment: please add the log contents

Comment: But it renders something? Can you provide the HTML code, generated by Rails?

Comment: @MarekLipka a lot of js and css code and yield as was usual in rails 3.2

Comment: please add the layout contents.

Comment: rails picks up 'application.html.haml' layout by default. Is your layout named the same or something different? From the log, it hasn't even rendered the layout. Is 'SomeController' inheriting 'ApplicationController'?

Comment: @prasad.surase jep and this is strange. What can cause it? Routes? render text: "test" is working ok if I'm adding it to controller.

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` and add the output to the question please.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I have a lot of routes and I can't post them all. But then I'm commenting it and leaving only root :to => "some/index" it returns me the same response.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12888 same is here, but I can't find how it was fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I've fixed it.
I've tried a lot of methods to identify and\or fix this weird bug, but didn't find it.
The last step was

```
$ cd ..
$ rails new previous_app_name
```

And used `d` diff to add rails4 missed configs. And `n` to skip all changes.
Dirty way, but if you will have such problems and will accurately add or change lines, everything will be good ;)